# How do I read from a specific line in a file?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int k = 0;
    int n;
    int y[0];
    cout << "write n\n";
    cin >> n;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("xxx.in.txt");
    infile >> y[0];
    infile.close();
    for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        for(int j = 1; j < n; j++)
            if(y[x] > y[j])
                k = k++;
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("xxx.out.txt");
    outfile << k;
    outfile.close();
}
```

file`xxx.in` contains two lines (it is a text file).

The first line has `n` amount of numbers, the second line has random numbers spaced apart.

I want to read from the second line.

How do I do this?

Comment: You could search StackOverflow for examples:  "c++ read file numbers".

Comment: BTW: `k = k++;` is [Undefined Behavior (UB)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984). `int y[0];` is just ill-formed. But no worries, accessing any element of a 0-element-array is UB again.

Comment: what is ub?????thanks for explaining

Comment: UB = [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to get input from the second line of your text file.

1. If you know how long the first line is you could use [istream::seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/).

   ```
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("xxx.in.txt");
    infile.seekg(length_of_first_line); // This would move the cursor to the second line.
    // Code to read line 2.
   ```
2. If you do not know the value or it could change. Then you would need to use [istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) and discard the first line.

   ```
    char buffer[256];
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("xxx.in.txt");
    infile.getline(buffer, 256); // Read in the first line.
    // Code to read line 2.
   ```

Comment: A more C++ way of using `getline` is with a string so you don't have to worry about 'only' reading 256 chars. `getline(infile, myString)`

Answer (score 0):

### Input from text file:

With the use of `<vector>`, `<fstream>` and `<sstream>` you can use something along the lines of the following function:

```
using namespace std;    

vector<vector<int> > getNumbers(string FileName) {
    vector<vector<int> > Numbers;            //Stores all the file's numbers
    ifstream infile(FileName.c_str());       
    string String;                           
    int a;
    while (getline(infile, String)) {        
        vector<int> Line;                    //Stores each line's numbers
        stringstream Stream(String);         
        while (Stream >> a)                  //Extracts numbers from 'Stream'
            Line.push_back(a);               //Each number is added to Line
        Numbers.push_back(Line);             //Each Line is added to Numbers
    }
    return Numbers;
}
```

It returns a two-dimensional vector of `ints`, where in `getFileNumber[x][y]` the `x` value is the line number (starting at value 0 for line 1), and the `y` value is the position of the number on the line (0 for the first number).

For example, in a file containing:

```
464 654334 35665 3456332 4454
2456 788654 3456 5775
```

The number `3456` would be `getFileNumbers[1][2]`

### Output to another text file:

To copy the entire contents of the `getFileNumbers` vector to a text file, you'd do this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > Numbers = getFileNumbers("xxx.in.txt");
std::ofstream Output("xxx.out.txt");
for (unsigned int y = 0; y < Numbers.size(); ++y) {
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < Numbers[y].size(); ++x)
        Output << Numbers[y][x] << ' ';
    Output << '\n';
}
```

### Line specific output:

If you wanted to output line `x` of a file with `std::cout`, you'd do this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > Numbers = getFileNumbers("xxx.in.txt");
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Numbers[x].size(); ++i)
    std::cout << Numbers[x][i] << ' ';
```

If you wanted to output line `x` to a file, you'd simply replace `std::cout` with a `std::ofstream` or `std::fstream` object.

Comment: `std::fstream << Numbers[x][i] << ' ';` which `i` is the line of the file?

Comment: where is `getFileNumbers` declared?